# Button doesn't work when updating cards category

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Trying to update the cards by filtering them depending on clicked category. Cards are updated but button on the updated cards don't work. After tests, it became obvious that the button doesn't work only on the places where previous cards appeared. If there's no card on previous filter and new card appears on empty place, button does work.
Here's my code. What's wrong? Does it update my cards properly?

```
var cards = d3.select('.card-columns')
    .selectAll('.card')
    .data(
        data1.filter(function(d) {
            return (status == "" || status == d.status) && (category == "" || category == d.category)
        }));

cards.exit().remove();

cards.enter()
    .append("div")
    .classed("card animated fadeInUp", true)
    .merge(cards)
    .style("border-top", function(d) {
        return "6px solid" + dateColor(d.status)
    })
    .html(function(d, i) {
        return drawCard(d, i);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind that D3 selections are immutable. That means that `cards` always refers to the same thing, regardless the use of `merge`. Therefore, you have only an "enter" selection with an `html` method.

To change `cards`, you have to reassign it:

```
cards = cards.enter()
    //etc...
    .merge(cards)
    //etc...
```

Here is how the whole snippet should be:

```
var cards = d3.select('.card-columns')
    .selectAll('.card')
    .data(data1.filter(function(d) {
        return (status == "" || status == d.status) && (category == "" || category == d.category)
    }));
cards.exit().remove();
cards = cards.enter()
    .append("div")
    .classed("card animated fadeInUp", true)
    .merge(cards)
    .style("border-top", function(d) {
        return "6px solid" + dateColor(d.status)
    })
    .html(function(d, i) {
        return drawCard(d, i);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for response, Gerardo! But button still doesn't work. The same result as was before :(

Comment: I found my mistake. Thanks.